# 49cc scooter shuts off after back tire stops or touches ground

Tags: maintenance

I recently changed the drive belt on my 49cc scooter. But when I did, it won't drive and for me to start it I have to make sure the back tire isn't touching the ground. If the back tire is stopped in any way such as hitting the back brakes or having the tyre on the ground it shuts off.

When its idling the back tire spins fast.

What would cause this and how can I fix it?

I'm pretty sure its a Japanese scooter.

Comment: If you'd like better help, why don't you start by editing your post and putting some information into it about what type of scooter it is (brand/model/year) ... telling us it's a 49cc scooter tells us next to nothing about how we might be able to help you. You could also possibly post some pics (even if you linked from PhotoBucket or Pintrest or something) of the engine clutch area.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing your scooter model/brand, I would suggest the problem is the centripetal clutch is hanging (or engaging all of the time). You may have made the belt too tight in the process of replacement. If you replace the clutch as well, it probably needs adjusted.

Comment: Ok I appreciate the help. But how would I take some tension off the belt. Not make it so tight. Because see I used some tools to help me put the but on without taking the varatior or the clutch off... Only because I couldn't break that nut loose. So what would you suggest I do? Thanks for your help...

Comment: Josh - add info into your original post to let us know what type of scooter it is, as belt tensioning will be different on different models.

Comment: @RoryAlsop ... I'm not sure he's going to be able to, actually. If you'll notice, it's a different user name, which implies to me two separate accounts (Josh v. Joshua).

Comment: well spotted - I just saw the gravatar as the same. Okay - if he posts extra info as an answer we can always edit it into the OP.